# How can I import a function from a file in racket?

Tags: racket

I'm sure this is am extremely basic question, but I have two files and I want to import one function from that file into the other one. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `provide` within a module to export definitions to other modules that import it with `require`:

```lisp
;; a.rkt
(provide f)
(define (f x)
  (displayln (add1 x)))

;; b.rkt
(require "a.rkt")
(f 3) ; => 4
```

For more information, [see the docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-basics.html).

Comment: Lana, you've asked a few questions. You got excellent answers. You haven't yet marked any as Accepted, yet. Tip: You probably should, otherwise people might not bother to answer anymore.