# How to include another file of definitions in current Racket file?

Tags: racket

I've tried:

```
#lang racket
(require foo.rkt)
```

and

```
#lang racket
(require "foo.rkt")
```

and

```
#lang racket
(require (relative-in "." foo.rkt))
```

If a straightforward example to just include one file in the current file's directory exists in the documentation, I cannot find it. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I import a function from a file in racket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756477/how-can-i-import-a-function-from-a-file-in-racket)

Comment: Also, depending on what you want, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809433/including-an-external-file-in-racket might be helpful, too.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Although that person asked for importing a specific function. However, the answer given *was* for a file.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that you were missing a `provide` in the other file?

Comment: Ya, while very close, I think they are distinct enough that they merit their own questions. Although they seem exactly the same to the two of us, I think that someone very new to Racket would find them to be distinct questions. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second guess is actually correct:

```
#lang racket
(require "foo.rkt")
```

However, what you need to do is also [`provide`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=provide#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._provide%29%29) the functions you would like to require from the other file, otherwise no variables from `foo.rkt` will be bound in your module.

So an example of a `foo.rkt` file would be:

```
#lang racket ; foo.rkt
(provide x)
(define x 5)
```

(The location of the provide does not matter, and can be above or below the `define` statement.)

If you want, you can use `all-defined-out` to export everything a module can provide in one go. To do this:

```
#lang racket ;  foo.rkt
(provide (all-defined-out))
(define x 5)
(define y 6)
```

Now you can require this file and use `x` and `y` in another module:

```
#lang racket
(require "foo.rkt")
x  ; => 5
```

Note that the two files need to be in the same directory, otherwise you will need to pass in the path to that directory. Such as:

```
(require "subdir/to/foo.rkt")
```

As a first addendum, Racket also has `import` and `load`. In general, you do not want these, and should generally stick to the `require`/`provide` pair.

As an second addendum, local files that you create are passed into `require` as a string. When its a symbol, such as in: `(require pict)`, that means you are requiring an installed module. While its more advanced you *can* make one of those by reading the [documentation on collections](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-basics.html?q=collections#%28part._link-collection%29).

Comment: is there any way to provide all the definitions without referring to each function name explicitly?