# Is it possible to use `provide` in Racket's Student Language?

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

`2.rkt` has the following definition:

```
(provide plus)

(define (plus a b)
  (+ a b))
```

and `1.rkt` has:

```
(require "2.rkt")

(plus 3 4)
```

Both are in "Beginning Student Language" level (so no `#lang` line required) and are in the same directory.

This leads to a **provide: this function is not defined** error in `2.rkt`.

Adding `(require racket/base)` in `2.rkt` fixes this but then I can do things like `(cons 1 2)` which shouldn't be allowed in BSL.

How can I use `plus` in `1.rkt` in BSL?

Comment: See [_BSL (How to Design Programs): how to import code from a separate file into definitions area?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653570/bsl-how-to-design-programs-how-to-import-code-from-a-separate-file-into-defin)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for